# How to use getchar() function from a stored string array?

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

I wrote a simple C program in Linux that reads a single character from a string. I get some error regarding string functions. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main () {
  char arr[10], vv[10];
  int i = 0, len;

  printf("enter the staement\n");
  scanf("%s", arr);
  len = strlen(arr);
  printf("String laength=%d\n", len);

  while ((vv[i] = getchar(arr)) != '\n') {
    printf("%d charcter\n");
    i++;
  }
}
```

I don't want to use `getchar()` directly on the input text like this:

```
arr[i] = getchar();
```

I want to use `getchar()` from a stored string like this:

```
getchar(string array);
```

But unfortunately I get an error. Can I use the `getchar()` function directly from a stored string array?

Comment: But `arr` is an array, so just use `arr[x]` where `x` is the character number you want to get?

Comment: There are also other problems with your code, like there not being a newline in the string you read with `scanf`, and many more.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg you dont need `'\n'` when you read a string! right?

Comment: Your last "`prinf`" dosen't make any sense.

Comment: This `prinf("%d charcter\n");` has no integer argument passed to print!

Comment: But when i use code `while( (vv[i]=getchar(arr[i]))!='\n')` same error like too many arguments to function ‘getchar’

Comment: function `getchar` takes no arguments.

Comment: Why don't you just use `while( (vv[i] = arr[i])!='\n')` ?

Comment: i want to get each character from a string called arr .

Comment: @user39133 added my answer! hope you get it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read about [`getchar`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_getchar.htm). The link clearly says that `getchar` is a function that gets a character (an `unsigned char`) from `stdin`. Also, it takes no arguments. This would mean that you cannot copy each character of an array to another array using `getchar`. Just copy it directly using

```
while( (vv[i] = arr[i]) != '\n')
```

But I don't think this loop will end as `scanf` does **not** include the newline character when scanning a string(`%s`). So,you got two options:

1. Use `fgets` to get input.
2. Use the following

   ```
   while( (vv[i] = arr[i]) != '\0')
   ```

Answer (score 1):

`vv` is a single `char`. You may not write `vv[i]`.

Also, are you sure you want `\n` and not `\0` [null]? `scanf()` won't give you a *string* with `\n` in it.

EDIT:

It is still unclear what you want to achieve, but if you want to check the presence of *valid* characters in the `arr` or `vv`, you can

1. take the base address of the `arr` or `vv` into a `char *p`.
2. check `if (*p++)` and `do something`.

EDIT:

You may try out something like

```
char * ip = NULL;
char * op = NULL;
int i = 10;              //same as array size.

ip = arr;
op = vv;

while( (*op++ = *ip++) && i--)
{

    //do something
};
```

Comment: sry , change to vv[10] array

Comment: @user39133 don't change the question in place. Now this answer does not make sense and I was going to downvote.

Answer (score 1):

When you have string in C, it is actually an array of `char`s which is terminated by '\0'. You do not need any method to get `char`s from it. Simply get the `char` as if you were accessing an array.

```
while((vv[i] = arr[i])!='\n')
```

As you have you `arr[10]` it will cause issues when your input is larger than 10 characters including the `'\0'`. So it is be better to declare it with enough space!